# How to refresh map only on click category?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can some help me to solve this problem 
I have a map on my website and i want to refresh map only on clicking on category my [this is my product](http://www.shopadspace.com/test)

```
          <?php
          /* $message = "in home";
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";*/

          foreach($categories as $category){
            echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0); "onclick="javascript:changeData'.base_url('main/home/' .$category->adv_category).'"><img src="'.base_url('uploads/'.$category->image).'" alt="'.$category->cat_name.'" width="30" height="30"/></br><span>'.$category->cat_name.'</span></a></li>';
          }
      ?>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

    function changeData(category){

      var urlCI = '.base_url('main/home/' .$category->adv_category).';

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlCI,
        data:{'categoryReq':category},
        success: function(response) {
          if(response!=''){
            $('map_marker').html(response);
          }else{
            return false;
          }
        }
      });

    }
</script>
```

my controller code is if you need other code please ask i will give. I give this just for refrence, thank you

```
public function home($cat=NULL)
{
    //$cat=10;

    //echo debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];

    if($_POST)
    {
        print_result($_POST);
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM (`ad_category`) WHERE `status`=1 AND `del_status`=0";
    $this->data['categories']=$this->db->query($sql)->result();

    if($cat)
    {
        //$message = $cat;
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";


        //$this->data['middle_view']='home_again';
        $this->data['ads']=$this->advt_m->get_advts($cat);
        $this->input->post('map_marker',$this->data);
        $this->data['subview']='home';
        $this->load->view('__layout_main',$this->data);
    }   
    else
    {
        /*$message = "Here 2";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";  
        */
        $this->data['subview']='home';
        //$this->data['middle_view']='home';
        $this->data['ads']=NULL;
        $this->load->view('__layout_main',$this->data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the Map div and its javascripts into another view.

Create function with all necessary functionalities for map. Add and load the it through Ajax call.

Ajax success:

```
success:function(response){
   $('div').html(response);
   //response will be the function which holds the $this->load->view('map');
}
```

map.php

```
<div id="map">
 YOUR MAP GOES HERE
</div>
<script>
 MAP SCRIPT
</script>
```

main.php (Your frontend)

```
<div id="map_here">

</div>

<script>
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  //Send some values
  data:{
       somevalue:'somedata',
       category:"mine"
       },
 url:"<?php echo base_url();?>mycontroller/mapfunc",
success:function(response){
 $('#map_here').html(response);
}
})
</script>
```

myconroller:

```
function mapfunc(){
 //Using this value you can change the script
 $data['category'] = $_POST('category');
 $data['location'] = $_POST('somevalue');
 //Process the works
 $this->load->view('map',$data);
 //On Ajax call this page can be loaded
}
```

Each ajax call it will reload the div.
any doubts just comment it...

Comment: can you please elaborate some ajax code, since i am new to ajax code need some example... thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlCI = '.base_url('main/home/' .$category->adv_category).';
```

probably should be

```
var urlCI = '<?php echo base_url("main/home/$category->adv_category"); ?>';
```

Comment: What is output in browser console?

Comment: javascript:void(0) is blocking the way 
and after removing javascript:void(0) browsr output is page not found but given url is correct.